# racket how to define function as another function in procedure

Tags: function, racket

I am trying to make a helper function that will take input of switched syntax.

Helper function needs to be able to do:

```
> (num sqr) ; where num=6, and sqr is the math function square.
36
```

Originally, the built-in syntax would be:

```
>(sqr num) ; where num=6
36
```

Since I cannot declare 'num' as a function and a variable at the same time, I will need to nest another procedure into it. Below is what I have so far:

```
(define (num func)
  (display func + 6))
```

Now, I know that 'display' won't easily do what I'd like it to do unlike other programming languages. Is there another method in place of 'display' that I can use? I think this is the easiest way to do it, but I am new so I'm not sure which is an appropriate method. 'func' will need to be able to take math functions like 'sqr' 'sqrt' 'add1'...etc.

Comment: It confuses me greatly that you're using `func` to reference the value passed to the `sqr` function, rather than the `sqr` function itself. In other words, if I see a variable named `func`, I expect it to be a function, not a number. Could you perhaps rename some variables so your logic flow is more clear?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. It's renamed.

Comment: Have you tried this in other languages? eg. `"Hello"(System.out.println);` in java??

Comment: No, I doubt it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want `(num sqr)` to work like in your code you can do this:

```
(define (num fun)
  (fun 6))

(num sqr) ; ==> 36
(num add1) ; ==> 7
```

But `num` won't be 6.

A solution might be to make yourself a module language, perhaps called `#!lefthanded-racket` where the parser for code just reverses all lists. Thus you can supply it code like:

```
#!lefthanded-racket

(6 num define)
(num sqr)  ; ==> 36
(num add1) ; ==> 7

((((((1 y -) x ack) (1 x -) ack) (y x))
                              (2 (1 _))
                        ((y 2 *) (y 0))
                              (0 (0 _)) 
                             (y x) match*)
                           (y x ack) define)
(4 2 ack) ; ==> 65536
```

For the simple solution, where you just override the default reader and deep reverse the lists you'll have problems with dotted lists. In order to get that right you need to write a parser.

The code that is run won't be in reverse, only the code you write. There is [some documentation on how to create your own language](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/languages.html). Also [this practical example](https://www.hashcollision.org/brainfudge/) might be helpful too.

Comment: I later found out the answer, and it is exactly what you wrote. Also thank you for extended reply that I can look into. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#lang racket
(define ((partial func) arg)
  (func arg))

((partial sqr) 6)
```

The output is 36.

Comment: No I want it to be just like the first sample code up there. Input must be (num sqr). The input you wrote is the syntax that Racket will originally take as shown in second sample code I wrote. That is why I need another nested procedure that would do something like (display func + 6).

Comment: Do you want to write (6 sqr) and get the result 36? If so, then you need to know that (6 sqr) expands to (#%app 6 sqr). Therefore you need to define a macro, say my-app, than turns (my-app 6 sqr) into (#%app sqr 6).